# Is this the correct way to wrap a method with a callback for async / await?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm working on a library that can send structured messages back and forth across the network. The library has a `Send` method that takes takes an `Action` as a callback.  When `Send` is called, the message is sent to the server, when a response is received to that message the stored callback is retrieved and executed.

This all works perfectly, but I would like to add a `SendAsync` method that wraps `Send` so that async / await can be used instead of directly passing an `Action`.  I've gotten it to work, but I don't know If I'm doing it correctly, or if I'll run in to problems later.  There is one line in particular that is really bothering me.

`Send` looks like this:

```
public void Send(Packet packet, Action<Response> callback)
{
    if (packet is Request)
    {
        RegisterResponseCallback(packet, callback);
    }
    Send(packet);
}
```

The async `SendAsync` looks like this:

```
public Task<Response> SendAsync(Request request)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();
    Send(request, (response) => { tcs.TrySetResult(response); });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I'm calling `SendAsync` a few time with this code, and I get the correct responses back in the correct order with the correct timing:

```
private async Task Connected()
{
    Console.WriteLine((await SendAsync(new EchoRequest() { Text = "Test 1" })).Message);
    Console.WriteLine((await SendAsync(new EchoRequest() { Text = "Test 2" })).Message);
    Console.WriteLine((await SendAsync(new EchoRequest() { Text = "Test 3" })).Message);
```

The line that is bothering me is the one that calls `Connected`.  It's inside a method that I don't want to mark `async` for various reasons.

```
protected override void StatusChanged(NetIncomingMessage message)
{
    switch (message.SenderConnection.Status)
    {
        case NetConnectionStatus.Connected:
            _serverConnection = new ServerConnection(this, message.SenderConnection);
            (new Task(async () => { await Connected(); })).Start();
            break;
    }
}
```

Specifically, the line that reads `(new Task(async () => { await Connected(); })).Start();` feels really "smelly" to me, but this was the only way I could figure out to get Visual Studio to stop giving me warnings.

Have I wrapped `Send` correctly for async /await, or will anything I've done here cause me problems further down the line?  Is there a better way for me to call `Connected`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `StatusChanged` is an event handler? Thus you need `async void`.

```
protected override async void StatusChanged(NetIncomingMessage message)
{
    //use await here
}
```

**EDIT** Since it's not an event handler, and you have various reasons not to mark it `async`, the only suggestion I can give is: using `Task.Run` instead of `new Task`, it's probably the most suitable solution here if you don't want to change the signature of the method.

```
Task.Run(async() => await Connected());
```

[`new Task` vs `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx)

[`Task.Run` vs `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

Comment: No, it isn't an event handler.  It's called from deeper down in the library as a result of a message being received from the server that is polled from a timer.  As such, `async void` feels wrong, everything I've read says that it is *usually* a mistake for anything that isn't an even handler to be declared async void.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes we should avoid using `async void` except for event handlers. Its name looks like a event handler for me. If it's a normal method, why can't you make it `async` then? You said `It's inside a method that I don't want to mark async for various reasons`.Why?

Comment: I'd have to change it to return a `Task`, correct?  Then whatever calls that would have to await it, and so on, until I have async and Tasks all the way down to `Main`.  I'll admit, I'm very new to async / await, so I may be misunderstanding something.  `StatusChanged` doesn't happen asynchronously at all, marking it with async and having it return tasks feels like I'm mixing async patterns in with code that I never intended to make happen asynchronously.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Correct. And yes, "all the way down".

Comment: Is this what you mean by using `Task.Run`?  `Task.Run(() => { Connected(); });`.  I get warnings about "Connected not being awaited" on that, trying to `await` it tells me I need to make `StatusChanged` `async`, and I end right back where I started with not liking my original line.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, that doesn't give me any warnings.  Can I ask what the difference is between my original `(new Task(async () => { await Connected(); })).Start();` and `Task.Run(async() => { await Connected(); });`?  It certainly *looks* cleaner to me, but is there a behavioral difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106306/discussion-between-danny-chen-and-bradley-uffner).